# Android Custom Listview with dynamic elements

Tags: android, listview

I want to create a custom ListView for a Drawer Navigation. 
The List should be like:
Headline
  sub-category
  sub-category
  sub-category
Headline
  sub
Headline
Headline

my problem is, that not every category has same amount of subs. 
can anyone tell how to create such a list ?

thanks in advance

Comment: Have you looked at a expandable Listview? You can group your items and make a grou header

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like what you want is an `expandable listview`.

Please have a look [here](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/07/android-expandable-list-view-tutorial/) at the tutorial or at the [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.html) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

You should use [Expandable ListView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.html)

Check it whether it fulfills your requirement..

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need expandable headers:
You need create some types of list items(Headline, sub). See tutorial: http://android.amberfog.com/?p=296
Else you can use expandablelist.